# Downward predictions in timeseries

Tags: python, time-series, data-science, arima

I am working on a project trying to predict the revenue over the next 12 months, but when I run the predictions and plot it, the future prediction show a consistant downward trend. I used the ARIMA model to get my data stationary but not sure why this is happening. Can someone explain what this means, and why the predictions are just falling. [Original Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBr2l.png)
[Original vs Predicted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVKXs.png)

Comment: "what this means" - the model "thinks" that there will be a downward trend, presumably because the last few observations showed such a trend. Also, one year into the future seems to be too long of a forecast horizon: any model will start predicting a straight line at some point [citation needed].

Comment: @ForceBru could this also be caused by extreme outliers in the data, which could throw the data off?

Comment: Maybe. I think the forecast horizon is the problem here: try forecasting the next two or three observations instead of a full year.